# If in doubt, post the question on Meta first?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, asking-questions, meta

Not for lack of trying, I get downvotes on some questions. And on those questions I nevertheless often get answers. So if I try to delete the question to approach it differently, I get the warning that doing this repeatedly can get my account question-banned by the system.

Should I instead first post a question draft on Meta if I have any doubt about its suitability? Is it really what Meta is for?

And as a side note: shouldn't SE sites have a draft/review section where people can get feedback on questions before they ask it? Because once a question has both answers and downvotes, even with significant improvements, the downvotes seem to severely impact chances of further answers.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The best thing to do is to read the Help Center, and specifically, in your case, where your questions are not off-topic, but not that well received:

## [How do I ask a good question?](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask)

That said, Meta is not meant to check if a question is OK before asking it, usually. The guidelines are pretty clear, and generally downvotes are used by members to indicate it is not a very good question, i.e.: it's not off-topic, but it could be improved. Meta can be used to ask about a specific type of question, if it's unclear per the guidelines whether it would be on-topic. The [on-topic](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/on-topic) tag is used for those.

Rather, Meta is intended to discuss how the site works and the various minutiae that comes into play, including specific posts. If you feel that a post you made was mishandled, then ask on Meta and use the [specific-question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-question) or [specific-answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/specific-answer) accordingly.

---

If you are truly unsure, feel welcome to drop by [The 2nd Monitor](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) chat room and ask about it. Just put your post in a PasteBin or Gist and we can have a look. This is generally not needed, but it is an option for you to get feedback ahead of time.

---

As far as drafts go, Stack Exchange does save an unpublished copy of your post, should you navigate away from the page, but other than that, there is not a system to manage draft versions of your posts. If you wish to request such a feature, you should post on [Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) with the `feature-request` tag.

Comment: PPCG has a meta "sandbox" post for question prep.  On CR, some people have asked people in the chat to read the post in a Gist...

Comment: @Hosch250 thanks I added this suggestion to the post.

Comment: Meta.CR also contains a wealth of information about writing good CR posts. [Here](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/1954/checklist-for-how-to-write-a-good-code-review-question?rq=1) would be one.

Comment: Beautiful post!